# Unable to detect device via bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am trying to detect **raspberry pi** device from my iPad.
I made my iPad as a central by using **CoreBluetooth.framework**. I am trying to scan services by passing service_UUID of raspberry pi

```
- (void)scan
{
         [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]]

                               options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];

         NSLog(@"Scanning started");
}
```

But not able detect the device.
The profile is mentioned as SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE in the raspberry code.

```
  advertise_service(service_sock,"RPi WiFi config",
                      service_id = uuid,
                     profiles = [SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE])
```

Is this is the problem. Can you suggest what should be done

Comment: If it is a legacy serial port profile,  it will not be visible to Core Bluetooth. The first you should do is download the Light Blue app from the App Store and check that it can see your peripheral.  If it can’t then you have an issue on your RPi. If it can then you have an issue in your iOS code; show more of it.

Comment: @Paulw11 : Thanks for reply..I tried downloading LIght Blue and BLE scanner on your suggestion. It is listing so many devices, but other than Apple devices everything is listing as "Unnamed". So how do I found it

Comment: You need to look at the service that is being advertised and see if you can find the service that is being advertised by your RPi. You could also try shutting down your RPi and see if one disappears

Comment: @Paulw11 : I didn't found any. There are number of devices listing. Earlier you mentioned CoreBluetooth can't discover serial_port profiles, if so what should be the solution .Is there any way to connect to serial_port_profiles? or if not at all possible anything should be done at RPi level

Comment: Only mfi certified devices can use the serial port profile. Normally BLE peripherals implement two characteristics; one to send data and one to receive.